# How to overcome this build error when trying to run jetpack compose instrumentation tests

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-instrumentation, jetpack-compose-navigation

I've followed the [jetpack compose navigation codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#0). Everything was going well until it came to testing the NavHost in step 7.
When trying to run the tests, I get the following error and stack trace :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:188)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:174)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
    .....
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessTestManifest.handleMergingResult(ProcessTestManifest.kt:331)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessTestManifest.mergeManifestsForTestVariant(ProcessTestManifest.kt:301)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessTestManifest.doFullTaskAction(ProcessTestManifest.kt:111)
    .....
```

There is a problem with the merged Manifest, but within the `androidTest` directory I have no Manifest, so as far as i can see, I have no control over what's in the generated one.

I can see the Merged Manifest from the `main` directory and there are no errors present in there. I can see the generated manifest in the build folder and it does display a load of errors.

Is there some technique I could use to attempt to resolve this?

EDIT:
Further investigation shows the problem as

```
android-compose-codelabs/NavigationCodelab/app/build/intermediates/tmp/manifest/androidTest/debug/tempFile1ProcessTestManifest6269584048200983460.xml Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

`android:exported` has been declared in the `main/AndroidManifest.xml` as expected, and it is also present in each component in the generated merged manifest for `androidTest`.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/issues/214#issuecomment-961222002). Adding the following dependency should solve the problem:

```
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3"
```

From the comment:

> Essentially, Android 12 introduced the requirement to specify the android:exported value on all activities when you have an intent-filter defined. This is causing issues right now because some libraries haven't updated to handle this change properly.